# How was the word2vec model trained?

Tags: neural-networks, training, backpropagation, word2vec, cbow

Let's take the CBOW (continuous bag of words) model as the example.

Suppose that, there are $c$ context words, each of which is a one-hot encoding vector. So the total number of elements of input vector is $v \cdot c$, where $v$ is the total number of words to be learned.

Suppose the first hidden layer has $d$ neurons, which is the size of the embedding dimension.

So all weights (or: embedding) parameters that are to be learned can be arranged in a $v \times d$ matrix.

My question is concerning how many weight parameters are updated during each training epoch for the word2vec model. Are all the $v \cdot d$ embedding, parameters updated during each training epoch? Or, are only $c \cdot d$ of them updated during each training epoch? Here the $c \cdot d$ embedding parameters are for the input context words.

If all $v \cdot d$ weights got updated during each epoch, it would be much more expensive, considering that the typical value of $v$ ranges from tens of thousands to hundreds of thousands.

I suppose, maybe a detailed backprop formulation would help me understand this. Where can I find such a detailed formulation? I'm not looking for a general theoretical backprop formulation, but seeking the one for the word2vec (e.g., the CBOW model).

Comment: Have you looked into this code, https://github.com/tmikolov/word2vec/blob/master/word2vec.c? The programmer, Thomas, is one of writers of Efficient Estimation of Word Representations in
Vector Space (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.3781.pdf)

Comment: @CloudCho Thank you so much for the code and paper links. They are very helpful. I will look into them. I don't have enough point in this community, otherwise I'd have voted up your comment.

Comment: Please, consider putting your study in the Answer section. Putting own answer isn't a bad practice unless you mark as the "Accepted Answer" :).